# Using paginator for view template navigation

Tags: cakephp, pagination, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

Can the paginator be hi-jacked for view template navigation (ie. provide next/prev URLs)?

I currently have a paginator with 1 row per page. I wanted to modify the URLs to point to the current view, but with the row PK instead of the :page querystring parameter.

1. First, visit model/view/5
2. In the paginator URls:

   - Next link, would go to model/view/6
   - Previous link, would go to model/view/4
   - Paged links, would go to model/view/x

Is this possible? Can pagination URLs be rewritten in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible, yes. First you need an appropriate route that makes use of an route element named `page`, like:

```
Router::connect('/model/view/:page', [
    'controller' => 'Models',
    'action' => 'view'
]);
```

This is required, as the paginator helper will set the page number via a key named `page` in the URL array when generating links. If you hadn't an element with that name in the route, the value would end in the query string. It is also important to not mark the `page` element as to be passed, as otherwise the value would slip into the URL arrays that the paginator helper generates, and that wouldn't match your route anymore.

The other thing you'd need to do, would be to make sure that the paginator component has access to the requested page number. By default the component reads the value from either the request query string variables, or from the pagination options. So, in the controller for example you could do something like:

```
$page = $this->request->param('page');
if ($page !== null) {
    $this->paginate['page'] = $page;
    // or
    $this->request->query['page'] = $page;
}

// ...

$result = $this->paginate();
```

For something more dry you could move this in a custom component, or an extended paginator component.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Passing Parameters to Actions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)**
- **[API \Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent::$_defaultConfig](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Controller.Component.PaginatorComponent.html#$_defaultConfig)**

Comment: Hrm... with the page number becoming the parameter, and more records to be added, it would be now impossible to bookmark it and expect the same data? The more I think about it, the more impractical this seems to be. It would be nice to be able to build the links, while providing the PK of the record at the end of the URL from within the pagination...

Comment: Well, if bookmarking is what you want to support, then this isn't a suitable solution, no. Paginating with primary keys, or any columns for that matter, is out of scope of the built in paginator, and is a task that is very different to your original question. @TekiusFanatikus